# How do I install dvd-slideshow on Centos 5?

Tags: linux, centos, software-installation, conversion

How do I install `dvd-slideshow` on Centos 5?

http://dvd-slideshow.sourceforge.net/wiki/Main_Page

I tried but only found a gui to install on Ubuntu.

I'm using Centos 5, command line.

Comment: I would also like to know this, I got as far installing "APT" on the cent os box, but now I'm seeing this: E: Couldn't find package dvd-slideshow